# Manipulating lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Assume I have two lists: 
`A[1,1]={1,2}` and `A[2,1]={3,4}`.

When I create a table

```
Table[A[i,j],{i,1,2},{j,1,1}]
```

I get

> {{{1,2}},{{3,4}}}

How can I have a result `{{1,2},{3,4}}`? Of course, using `Table` or some other function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table[A[i, 1], {i, 1, 2}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

Alternatively,

```
A[#, 1] & /@ {1, 2}
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

Also

```
Flatten[Table[A[i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 1}], 1]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

Comment: Last option was an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples):

```
Tuples[A[{1,2}, {1}]]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}